# mips extract certain bits from register and set them to a different register in the same place without changing the rest

Tags: mips

I'm trying to pull bits 15 to 31 from register $t0 and set them to the same positions in register $t1.

How can I do this in the least possible instructions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At a basic level, you can get the values of certain bits from a register by ANDing the register with 0s where you want to ignore the old value and 1s where you want to respect it.

If you want to then combine that with bits from another input, do that same technique on the second input with the opposite 1s and 0s on the value you AND them with. Then, add the two resultant values together.

So for example (pseudoy, with values instead of registers):

```
AND 0001010101 0000001111 = 0000000101
AND 1101101101 1111110000 = 1101100000
ADD 1101100000 0000000101 = 1101100101
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, lets define $t0 as being equal to a 16 bits value (because its easier), let's say `1010 1100 0101 1000`.

Then lets say $t1 have the value of `1100 0101 1011 1110`.

And we want to put the first 5 bits of $t0 into the same fields of $t1. Then we need to follow these steps :

1. Make an `and` operation between $t0 and another register. Notice that the "other register" need to have all the bits different from the ones we want extract as being equal to zero, meanwhile all the bits that have the same "index" of the bits we want to extract need to be equal to one. Example  :

```
1010 1100 0101 1000
0000 0000 0001 1111
-------------------
0000 0000 0001 1000
```

let's put this result in the register $s0

2. Make the same thing with $t2, but now all the fields of $t2 that we want to substitute (the 5 first bits) need to perform an and operation between a register that has just zeros in the matching indexes, meanwhile all the others bits need to be equal to 1. Example :

```
1100 0101 1011 1110
1111 1111 1110 0000
-------------------
1100 0101 1010 0000
```

lets put this result on $s1

3. In order to substitute the first 5 bits of $t1 by the first bits of $t0, you just need to do :

```
xor $t1, $s0, $s1
```

*OBSs* :

1.When I said "the first 5 bits of the register $t0" on the third paragraph, I was make reference to the *LSB's*