# Is there any way of inicializing a variable with a binary value in MIPS?

Tags: binary, initialization, mips

I need to initialize an register with an specific decimal value in order to extract the bits of another register ([by doing this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32752682/mips-extract-certain-bits-from-register-and-set-them-to-a-different-register-in/74199895#74199895)). The only problem is, since I need to do an `and`operation with a very large decimal, it turns out to be very difficult to convert a binary number into a decimal number without a calculator to perform this operation.

So I am interested to know if there is any way of initializing a register with a binary value directly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your assembler/simulator does not allow you to write binary constants but it allows you to write hexadecimal ones then you may easily encode a binary number in hexadecimal.

Starting from the least significand bit, every 4 bits you encode its hexadecimal value using the following table:

```
0000 - 0
0001 - 1
0010 - 2
0011 - 3
0100 - 4
0101 - 5
0110 - 6
0111 - 7
1000 - 8
1001 - 9
1010 - A
1011 - B
1100 - C
1101 - D
1110 - E
1111 - F
```

If the original binary number does not have a multiple of 4 bits you fill the most significand bits to 0 until it fills the last packet.

For example, you may encode this words in hexadecimal converting them from binary numbers:

```
myvar: .word 0x1234 # binary 1 0010 0011 0100
other: .word 0xCAFEBABE # binary 1100 1010 1111 1110 1011 1010 1011 1110
```

Comment: Did you try, for example, `.word 0b00001111000011110000111100001111`?

Comment: @puppydrum64: boolean constants are not accepted in MARS simulator. Probably didn't work in OP setting neither

Comment: That's annoying. Most assemblers I use let me use `%` or `0b` as a binary prefix.